# (closed) Create toast message inside a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-toast

I am trying to show a toast message in the DatabaseHandler class if an item is successfully added or failed to be add into the sqlite database.

I would like to know is it possible for a toast message to be created inside a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper?

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


/**
 * Storing item details in database
 * */
public void addItem(Items item) {    
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_IID, item.getIID()); // mysql item id
    values.put(KEY_NAME, item.getName()); // item name
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, item.getPrice()); // item price
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, item.getDate()); // Created At
    values.put(KEY_TYPE, item.getType()); // type

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_ITEM, null, values);

    //TOAST MESSAGE HERE

    db.close(); // Closing database connection
    } else {
        //TOAST MESSAGE HERE
        db.close();
    }  
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a good design approach. A `SQLiteOpenHelper` isn't a UI class so adding functionality which interacts with the UI doesn't make sense. Bearing in mind the `addItem(...)` method you've shown isn't a native method of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, why don't you just define it as `public boolean addItem(Items item)` and have it return a success/fail boolean to the `Activity` using it so the `Activity` can show the `Toast`.

Comment: yes, your suggested method is better. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, provided that you call the code in the main UI thread. Creating a `Toast` also requires a valid `Context` which you need to pass in as an argument.